# Node.js: Check if file is an symbolic link when iterating over directory with 'fs'

Tags: node.js, linux, fs, symlink-traversal, node-supervisor

Supervisor is a package for Node.js that monitors files in your app directory for modifications and reloads the app when a modification occurs.

This script interprets symbolic links as regular files and logs out a warning. I would like to fork Supervisor so that either this can be fixed entirely or that a more descriptive warning is produced.

How can I use the File System module of Node.js to determine if a given file is really an symbolic link?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [`fs.lstat`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_lstat_path_callback) and then call [`statis.isSymbolicLink()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_stats_issymboliclink) on the [`fs.Stats`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) object that's passed into your lstat callback.

```
fs.lstat('myfilename', function(err, stats) {
    console.log(stats.isSymbolicLink());
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you can use [isSymbolicLink()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dirent_issymboliclink)

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(dir, {encoding: 'utf8', withFileTypes: true});
files.forEach((file) => {
  if (file.isSymbolicLink()) {
    console.log('found symlink!');
  }
}
```